# Coldfulsion 7 (MX): Unable to read CF variables when bypass login

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I'm trying to figure out simply if a user is logged in or not.

Once the user logs in, I can print the username via #GetAuthUser()#. The page I created (ex. IsLoggedIn.cfm) will prompt for a login, **which is what I do not want**. I want to check if they are logged in without prompting. If I add IsLoggedIn.cfm to application.cfm, I will no longer be prompted to log in, but the login check (cfif #GetAuthUser()# is not "") fails, I'm no longer able to read variables, I guess it's a scope issue.

Isn't there a way to just check if they're logged in without it prompting them to login? This seems so simple, yet I can't find an answer anywhere...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance,
Bob :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no special trick to this.

In your log in code, just set `session.isLoggedIn = true`, and in your log out code, set it to `false`. Check that variable as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was my first check, but I have the same problem. I am unable to read ANY coldfusion variable after I add any file to application.cfm (requiring no log in to access)... I'm not sure what happens to the scope of the variables, or if there is an error in my application.cfm somewhere, but I'm stumped!

Comment: What do you mean "add any file to application.cfm"? Also... why are you using Application.cfm still (even on CFMX7)? Also, based on what you just said, you're asking the wrong question. This " I am unable to read ANY coldfusion variable after I add any file to application.cfm" (whatever that means) is a more pressing problem.

Comment: The site creators no longer exist, so I'm stuck with it. The site is set up so that any cfm file on the server will prompt the user to log in to access it; in application.cfm there are a few exceptions, for ex.: (CFIF (CGI.SCRIPT_NAME IS NOT "/Index.cfm"): prompt for login). So once the prompt is removed, I can access the file, but no cf variables. Do you mean the alternative to application.cfm is application.cfm? Yes I know the title is no longer relevant, I didn't realise until after I posted. Thanks again, hopefully that clarifies a few things.

Comment: I also think my initial question (explanation in paragraph one) explains clearly what I meant by adding the exception in Application.cfm, so I won't be prompted to log in to access that page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not that this makes any sense, but in the rare instance that this may help anyone else, I added the login bypass within the (cflogin) tags in the application.cfm file. now I'm able to access the variables i need.